# Dùvida em relação função e for

Tags: javascript

Preciso resolver essa questão:

> As árvores utópicas crescem de uma forma particular, em dois ciclos: a cada primavera dobram seu tamanho, a cada verão crescem um metro. Se Laura planta uma árvore utópica com um metro no final do outono, qual seria sua altura depois de N ciclos?
>
> Alguns exemplos:
>
> - se N = 0, sua altura será 1 metro (não cresceu nada);
> - se N = 1, sua altura será de 2 metros (dobrou a altura na primavera);
> - se N = 2, sua altura será de 3 metros (cresceu um metro a mais no verão);
> - se N = 3, sua altura será de 6 metros (dobrou a altura na primavera seguinte).

Não sei dizer se o meu código está sendo feito corretamente, mas segue ele abaixo:

```
function alturaArvoreUtopica(){
  var ciclos
  var tamanhoArvore = 1
  for(var i = 0; i <= ciclos; i++){
    if(????){
      return tamanhoArvore *= 2
    }else
      return tamanhoArvore +=1
  }
}
```

Comment: "Primavera" e "verão" representam quantos meses? A sua pergunta está um pouco vaga. Poderia fornecer um pouco mais de detalhes, por favor?

Comment: Oi Luiz, segue a questão abaixo:
As árvores utópicas crescem de uma forma particular, em dois ciclos:

cada primavera dobram seu tamanho
cada verão crescem um metro
Se Laura planta uma árvore utópica com um metro, no final do outono, qual seria sua altura depois de N ciclos?

Alguns exemplos:

si N = 0, sua altura será 1 metro (não cresceu nada)
si N = 1, sua altura será de 2 metros (dobrou a altura na primavera)
si N = 2, sua altura será de 3 metros (cresceu um metro mais no verão)
si N = 3, sua altura será de 6 metros (dobrou a altura na primavera seguinte)

Comment: No outono e inverno a árvore não cresce?

Comment: Não, somente nos ciclos de primavera e verão

Comment: A altura recebe + 1 no verão e na primavera a altura é multiplicada por 2?

Comment: Exatamente isso Luiz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse "ciclo" está estranho. Pela questão eu entenderia que um ciclo seria uma estação, mas no exemplo a arvore cresce durante todo ciclo, o que dá a entender que um ciclo seria verão+outono e inverno+primavera. Então nesse caso a arvore cresceria alternadamente.

```js
function alturaArvoreUtopica(ciclos) {
  let tamanhoArvore = 1;
  for(let i = 0; i < ciclos; i++)
    if(i & 1)
      tamanhoArvore += 1;
    else
      tamanhoArvore *= 2;

  return tamanhoArvore;
}


console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica(0));
console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica(1));
console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica(2));
console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica(3));
```

Comment: O que conta apenas no ciclo da árvore é que ela cresce apenas 2x o seu tamanho na primavera e +1 no verão, ela não cresce nas estações de outono e inverno

Comment: Eu entendi isso, mas a definição de "ciclo" não ficou clara.

Comment: O enunciado ficou um pouco confuso para mim também, mas pelo que eu entendi é o seguinte: Essa árvore ela cresce somente nas épocas de verão e primavera, sendo respectivamente +1 metro no verão e 2x metro na primavera, pode ser N ciclos, eu só preciso saber o tamanho final dela

Comment: O que significa if( i &1 ) que está no código?

Answer (score 3):

Assumindo que:

- A árvore começa com `1` metro;
- O crescimento começa no **verão**;
- Existem quatro estações, dispostas na seguinte ordem: `Verão -> Outono -> Inverno -> Primavera`
- E que o crescimento ocorra de modo que:

  - Verão: o tamanho da árvore aumenta em `1`;
  - Outono: o tamanho não é alterado;
  - Inverno: o tamanho não é alterado;
  - Primavera: o tamanho é multiplicado em `2`.

---

Podemos estipular que, se quisermos que ocorram 9 ciclos, o tamanho final será 11, já que:

```
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| Verão               | Outono    | Inverno   | Primavera | Verão     | Outono    | Inverno   | Primavera  | Verão       |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| 1 (inicial) + 1 = 2 | 2 + 0 = 2 | 2 + 0 = 2 | 2 * 2 = 4 | 4 + 1 = 5 | 5 + 0 = 5 | 5 + 0 = 5 | 5 * 2 = 10 | 10 + 1 = 11 |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

O código para calcular isso seria:

```js
function utopicTree(cycles = 1, initialLength = 1, seasonStart = 0) {
  const seasons = ['summer', 'autumn', 'winter', 'spring']
  let currentLength = initialLength

  for (let i = 0 + seasonStart; i < cycles + seasonStart; i++) {
    const currentSeason = seasons[i % seasons.length]

    if (currentSeason === 'summer') currentLength += 1
    if (currentSeason === 'spring') currentLength *= 2
  }

  return currentLength
}

// Ciclos = 9 / Tamanho inicial = 1 / Começa na estação = 0 (verão)
console.log(utopicTree(9, 1, 0))
```

---

Note que se você quiser desconsiderar os ciclos de "outono" e "inverno", basta removê-los do `array` de estações (*seasons*):

```js
function utopicTree(cycles = 1, initialLength = 1, seasonStart = 0) {
  const seasons = ['summer', 'spring']
  let currentLength = initialLength

  for (let i = 0 + seasonStart; i < cycles + seasonStart; i++) {
    const currentSeason = seasons[i % seasons.length]

    if (currentSeason === 'summer') currentLength += 1
    if (currentSeason === 'spring') currentLength *= 2
  }

  return currentLength
}

// Ciclos = 6 / Tamanho inicial = 1 / Começa na estação = 0 (verão)
console.log(utopicTree(6, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function alturaArvoreUtopica(nCiclos){// nCiclos é a quantidade de ciclos da arvore  
    var alturaResultante;  
    for(var i = 0; i <= nCiclos; i++){  
        if(i == 0){ // se o contador é igual a zero retorna o valor inicial da arvore  
            alturaResultante = 1;  // valor inicial da arvore  = 1
        }  
        if(i %2 == 0&& i != 0){  // se contador diferente de zero e par "mod=0"
            alturaResultante+=1;  // soma-se 1 metro à altura da arvore
        }  
        if(i % 2 != 0 && i != 0){  //se contador diferente de zero e impar "mod!=0"
            alturaResultante*=2;  // dobra o tamanho da arvore
        }  
    }  
    return alturaResultante;  
}  
console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sei que esta publicação tem um tempo já, mas me deparei com esse cenário e estava com dificuldade de entender também, o único que consegui entender mais ou menos foi a resposta do José Tomas, porém tinha uma expressão que não entendi e nunca tinha visto `if(i % 2)`, pesquisei e entendi, então ficou mais fácil e essa expressão pode ser entendida dessa forma: `if (i % 2 == 0)`. Que seria o resto da multiplicação por dois (pegando os ciclos pares) então ficou assim:

```
function alturaArvoreUtopica(n) {
let alturaArvore = 1;
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        alturaArvore += 1;
    } else {
        alturaArvore *= 2;
    }
return alturaArvore;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
function alturaArvoreUtopica(qtdCiclo){
  var arvore = 1
  for(var i = 0; i < qtdCiclo; i++){
    if(i % 2){
      arvore += 1;
    }else{
      arvore *= 2;
    }
  }
  return arvore
}
```

Assumindo que:

A árvore começa com 1 metro;
Não importa qual seja a estação do ano, sua ordem de ocorrência e que cada ciclo seja uma estação.
E que o crescimento ocorra de modo que:
Verão: o tamanho da árvore aumenta em 1;
Outono: o tamanho não é alterado;
Inverno: o tamanho não é alterado;
Primavera: o tamanho é multiplicado em 2.

Comment: Explique sua resposta forneça dados onde qualquer pessoa possa ler e entender sua resposta.

Answer (score -1):

```
// essa vai dar certinho

function alturaArvoreUtopica(n) {

var estacoes = []
var arvore = 1
if (n == 0) {
    return arvore;
} if (n == 1) {
    return arvore + 1;
}
for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

    if (i % 2 == 1 && i > 0) {
        estacoes.push("inverno")
    } if (i % 2 == 0 && i !== 0) {
        estacoes.push("verao")
    }
}
for (var c = 0; c <= estacoes.length; c++) {

    if (estacoes[c] === "inverno") {
        arvore = arvore * 2;
    }
    if (estacoes[c] === "verao") {
        arvore = arvore + 1;
    }
}
return arvore
```

}