# Dúvida em um código para calcular o crescimento de uma árvore

Tags: javascript, array, if, for

Estou tendo algumas dificuldades para fazer esse código abaixo funcionar. O enunciado do exercício é esse:

As árvores utópicas  crescem de uma forma particular, em dois ciclos:

- cada primavera dobram seu tamanho
- cada verão crescem um metro

Se Laura planta uma árvore utópica com um metro, no final do outono, qual seria sua altura depois de N ciclos?

Alguns exemplos:

si N = 0, sua altura será 1 metro (não cresceu nada);
si N = 1, sua altura será de 2 metros (dobrou a altura na primavera);
si N = 2, sua altura será de 3 metros (cresceu um metro mais no verão);
si N = 3, sua altura será de 6 metros (dobrou a altura na primavera seguinte);
E assim ...

> Escreva a função **alturaArvoreUtopica**, que utilize uma quantidade de ciclos de crescimento, e retorne a altura resultante da árvore de Laura.

Aí tem esse código abaixo:

```
function alturaArvoreUtopica(ciclos) {

const cicloInicial = 1;
const tamanhoInicial = 1;
const estacaoInicial = 0;

const estacoes = ['verao', 'primavera']
let tamanho = tamanhoInicial

for (let i = 0 + estacaoInicial; i < cicloInicial + estacaoInicial; i++) {
const estacao = estacoes[i % estacoes.length]

if (estacao === 'verao') tamanho += 1
if (estacao === 'primavera') tamanho *= 2
}

return tamanho
}
```

Mas está apresentando os seguintes erros:

**Sua solução não passou as provas
Objetivos que não foram atendidos:
 alturaArvoreUtopica faz comparações contra strings
Resultados do teste:
 alturaArvoreUtopica(0) 
2 == 1**

Gostaria de saber onde estou errando no código. Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Ah detalhe também, sendo mais específico, a ideia seria que a árvore cresce somente na primavera e no verão. Na Primavera ela cresce o dobro da altura, e no verão ela cresce mais um metro.

Comment: Possível duplicata de: [Dùvida em relação função e for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/366467/d%c3%b9vida-em-rela%c3%a7%c3%a3o-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-e-for)